# How to run a large file in batches in Python

Tags: python, batch-processing

I have below code  which gives road name and type of road (highway, service road etc) by using Overpy API from the csv file. Each file contains many rows (295741 rows) and when I am trying to run the code it gets stuck at a around 3000 row.

Can I process the file in batches, so that entire file can be processed?

```
import overpy
import pandas as pd
import time
import os


root = r'C:/Users/name/Documents/data'
fstem = 'sample'
fname = fstem+'.csv'
with open(os.path.join(root, fname)) as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
#df.sort_values(by=['cvdt35_timestamp_s'],inplace=True)
print('# of records = '+str(len(df)))
api= overpy.Overpass()

queries = []
names = []
highways =[]
results = []
df['Name']=''
df['Highway'] =''

radius = 10
for row in df.index:                                                                                            
    query = ('way["highway"](around:{},{},{}); out body;').format(radius,df.gps_lat_dd.iloc[row], df.gps_lon_dd.iloc[row])
    queries.append(query)

for i in range(len(queries)):
    result = overpy.Result()
    query = queries[i]
    print(str(i)+', '+query)
    while True:
        try:
            result = api.query(query)
            break
        except overpy.exception.OverpassTooManyRequests:
            print('OverpassTooManyRequests')
            time.sleep(10*6)
        except overpy.exception.OverpassBadRequest:
            break
    if result:
        results.append(result)
    else:
        results.append('NAN')

#    results.append(result)

names = []
highways = []
for result in results:
    n1 = []
    h1 = []
    if type(result) is not str:
        for way in result.ways:
            name = way.tags.get("name", "n/a")
            n1.append(name)
            highway = way.tags.get("highway", "n/a")
            h1.append(highway)
        names.append(','.join(n1))
        highways.append(','.join(h1))
    else:
        names.append('')
        highways.append('')


df['Name']=names
df['Highway']=highways


fname = fstem+'_op.csv'
df.to_csv(os.path.join(root,fname),header=True,index=False)
```

Sample data

```
RecordID    cvdt35_bus_r    GPS_Longitude_Degrees   GPS_Longitude_Minutes   GPS_Longitude_Min_dec   gps_lat_dd  gps_lon_dd  decimal
876 2   -83 10  0.8668  42.30721    -83.18111333    0.80899
877 2   -83 10  0.8668  42.30721167 -83.18111333    0.2055
878 2   -83 10  0.867   42.30721333 -83.18111667    0.56226
879 2   -83 10  0.8673  42.30721667 -83.18112167    0.27893
880 2   -83 10  0.8675  42.30722    -83.181125  0.8276
881 2   -83 10  0.8676  42.30722    -83.18112667    0.15108
882 2   -83 10  0.8676  42.30722167 -83.18112667    0.72718
883 2   -83 10  0.8675  42.30721667 -83.181125  0.89037
884 2   -83 10  0.8675  42.30721667 -83.181125  0.95866
885 2   -83 10  0.8675  42.30721667 -83.181125  0.95351
886 2   -83 10  0.8675  42.30721667 -83.181125  0.91884
887 2   -83 10  0.8675  42.30721667 -83.181125  0.97088
888 2   -83 10  0.8675  42.30721667 -83.181125  0.92894
889 2   -83 10  0.8675  42.30721667 -83.181125  0.92224
890 2   -83 10  0.8675  42.30721667 -83.181125  0.02049
```

There is no error that is displayed, the code just stops. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the reason it stops? Is it running out of memory? Is there some error?

Comment: Documentation says: Any of the three servers has a total capacity of about 1,000,000 requests per day. You can safely assume that you don't disturb other users when you do less than 10,000 queries per day and download less than 5 GB data per day. You are likely to reach your threshold.

Comment: If you're reliably hitting 3000 rows as a ceiling (which is odd - pandas is usually good for well over a million rows), wrap your code in a function and call the function with modulo logic.

Comment: There is no error , it just stops running the code.

Comment: Please read [mcve] to improve your post. At this point we do not have enough information to understand what is your issue, we could only guess it. Mainly details your input, expected output. Also check your index (size, type).

Comment: You're accumulating queries on the loop, this will increase memory linearly, you need pro process it in batches without accumulating in `queries`

Comment: How you use `queries`?

Comment: I am not sure how to pre process it in batches and I am running my queries in Spyder.

Comment: You might be interested in [dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html)

Comment: I tried using dask but no.of partitions it is showing in dask is only 1.